# An HTTP Content-Type header is required for SOAP messaging and none was found

Tags: c#, wcf, soap

maybe you could help me. i am trying to use wcf to transfer a string between client and server. most of the time it is working. but at some clients (one on particular) i received the following error "An HTTP Content-Type header is required for SOAP messaging and none was found". 
1. is this an error that returns from the server side ?
2. how can this be fixed ?

Thanks in advance
G.

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed this problem. I've increased WCF service server CloseTimeout Binding property to 5 minutes from default 1. It's server side problem.

Comment: I couldnt understand why they giving negative. It is work like that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I recently had this issue.
It turned out it is caused by the Azure web app load balancer time out

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps/suggestions/36572656-make-web-app-timeout-of-230-seconds-configurable

Because the server took longer than 230 seconds to process the request, so before the web service return the response, the load balaner will timeout and cut the TCP connection caused the ticket client receve a ProtocolException  with the message:

An HTTP Content-Type header is required for SOAP messaging and none was found.

Since we can not control or configure that timeout settings, eventually I have to modify the service to make the process shorter than 230 seconds.