Error connecting SOAP service : An HTTP Content-Type header is required for SOAP messaging and none was found
Recently, my hard drive has been changed and a fresh installation of Windows 11 done.
Since then, a SOAP service, from one of our subcontractor, doesn't work anymore on my computer in Rider.
When I contact it, I receive the following error message : An HTTP Content-Type header is required for SOAP messaging and none was found.
I don't have any access on this web service, it's hosted externally, so I can't change anything on it.
For test, I put my previous SSD in the computer and it's working fine, so there is no change on subcontractor service.
tls1.2 is force in code and service is TLS1.2
I have try recommendation I could fine on internet, but I'm still stuck.
I'm using Windows 11 Pro 23H2, Rider 2024.1.3 (or VS2022, same issue).
The application is in [tag:Framework 4.6.2] (MVC)
About code, it's exacty the same, the repository has been copied from previous drive to the new one.
I have googled and try what I could found about the error message : An HTTP Content-Type header is required for SOAP messaging and none was found

Was a Content-Type header sent before that is now missing? It was a good idea to try it out with the old installation, but please check the statement of the error message. Are you able to inspect how the request was composed with the old installation? It it spossible that the behaviour of one of the involved libraries has changed. This can be a bit difficult to pin down, but even if the explicitly written application code has not changed, something apparently has changed. From the distance, it is difficult to tell. Are you aware of what an HTTP header is?

Do you know what an HTTP header is in the first place (this is not meant as a challenge, but for clarification)?

Apparently this can also be caused by a timeout: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176624/an-http-content-type-header-is-required-for-soap-messaging-and-none-was-found

This also seems to address the issue: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/587187/wcf-accept-response-without-content-type

Perhaps I misread your question; is the HTTP header missing in the request or in the response?

To verify whether the Content-Type was missed from the server response or not, having a look at the WinHTTP logs would be helpful. Is there any difference between the working machine and the newer one?

Thanks all for your answers !
The issue is not solved yet but I have a better view now.
My initial request seems not accepted anymore, so I receive a response message with the specific error in it.
But this response message is not XML (or soap) compliant so I do have a ProtocolException. I don't know if it's the content (html instead of xml) or a missing header.
I'm waiting more informations from the WS creator.
I found the the issue with fiddler, more friendly than WinHTTP logs, thx for the suggestion.
Very strange we can't check the initial response received in code.

Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, accept the answer that you found most helpful. - From Review

Great that they helped you. If you have further questions, mark the answer you found helpful as correct, then ask them in a comment or new question instead.
